# Is there a way to execute rest of the script after performing window.location change?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Working on small chrome extension using manifest v3. Basically I have a line in my code that changes the window location to another page (it is required). The following line is supposed to find the element once the window has changed.

abstract:

```
window.location = "link to other web"
const element = document.querySelector("div")
console.log(element)
```

The problem is of course the fact that lines after window.location doesn't work because they do not exist anymore. Is there a way to keep the logic after the refresh/reload?

Perfectly if it would work like selenium (in brower, not in window). As mentioned I'm using manifest v3 api so maybe there is a way to keep the code...

Comment: To clarify: do you want `element` to refer to a `div` on the _new page_? Generally you cannot run code on pages you don't directly control — think about what could happen if a malicious page could move you to e.g. your bank and execute code there while you are logged in!

Comment: @EmmaKoskinen it appears to be a chrome extension, so, it can access any page it's been given access to anyway

Comment: @KevinB I'm unsure what you're trying to communicate with the '"Imagine if it was possible to do exactly what you were trying to do!"' comment. Was a leading question a bad approach in getting the OP to rethink the situation or? In whatever case I think sarcasm was uncalled for

Comment: @KevinB Even though it's a chrome extension, the fact that `window` is available tells us this is happening in the context of a page, doesn't it? I couldn't find a way to do what the OP is asking within content scripts, and do think it'd be a cross-site security vulnerability, but please do answer the original question if you know a way of doing this!

Comment: it isn't directly possible as written, but i don't think that's really what they're asking

Comment: Effectively, we need to know why this is needed and what the goal is. Because it isn't possible to do it the way they imagined, we need to know more about the scenario to recommend the correct approach to solve the actual problem

Comment: My initial remark was me seeing your note as comical, as you effectively said think about what you're asking for, when that's clearly what they're doing! the important question is *why*. if the why can't be answered, neither can the question